# SQL query to combine 2 date columns into a combined column

Tags: sql, date

I have a table with two different data columns that I want to combine into one column `l.date_Combined`.

First consider if there is a date in `l.date_time_ic`. If that is empty look for the date in `l.date_time_mc`. Place the result into `l.date_Combined`.

I was able to do the where clause but I don't know how to build the update logic for the combined field.

```
select
    l.id,
    l.date_time_ic,
    l.date_time_mc
from 
    new.customers l
where
    ((l.date_time_ic between '4/1/2018' and '4/30/2018') or
    (l.date_time_mc between '4/1/2018' and '4/30/2018' and
     l.date_time_ic is null));
```

Comment: Thanks for asking your first question, Matt!
You are going to need to use an SQL "update" instead of a select. Try W3Schools "Update" article to start: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Comment: Then when you have a better idea of how an update would work, maybe adjust the query you provided as an example, and the community can give you better help.

Comment: Just to add on use ISNULL /COALESCE function which might help you.

Comment: @M.K.Hunter - I wanted to stay away from using Update.

Comment: @RajatJaiswal how about using a Case statment? Im not aware of ISNULL /COALESCE. Thank you. I will look into this.

Comment: @Matt  You can use case as well. Although, ISNULL & COALESCE syntax is very simple. I am pretty much sure you will see and implement it real quick. Best of luck. RJ

Answer (score 3):

I believe you just want `coalesce()`.  More importantly, represent your dates using an ISO/ANSI standard format, such as YYYY-MM-DD:

```
select l.id,
       coalesce(l.date_time_ic, l.date_time_mc) as thedate
from new.customers l
where coalesce(l.date_time_ic, l.date_time_mc) >= '2018-04-01' and
      coalesce(l.date_time_ic, l.date_time_mc) < '2018-05-01' ;
```

You will notice that I changed the date logic to use comparisons rather than `between`.  [Here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) is a good blog on that subject.  Most of what is in the blog applies to all databases, not just SQL Server.

Comment: I will try this. Appreciate it.